# Create Class with another class

Tags: java

I decided to write my first Java Program-HotelPRO
.Classes are below:

```
package hotelpro;
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int PESEL;
    Room room;   
}

public class Room {
    int RoomNo;
    boolean Occupied=false;
    Room(int RoomNo){
    this.RoomNo=RoomNo;

    }   
}

package hotelpro;


public class HotelPro {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Room[] rooms=new Room[10];
          for (int i=0;i<rooms.length;i++)
          {
          rooms[i]=new Room(i);

          }

          for (int i=0;i<rooms.length;i++){
          System.out.println(rooms[i].RoomNo);
          System.out.println(rooms[i].Occupied);
          }




    }

}
```

So basically i created a Room with roomNumber and if its occupied.
Customer suppose to have a name,PESEL(polish id) and a room(which should be a constructor from Room class ?So all of the customers will have a room(default 0 which means no room) ) . Can You let me know how to do it ? i am pretty sure my code is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your code seems to create 10 empty rooms, and is correct. You want the sample code to create a Customer?

Comment: I am asking how to create proper a class which is taking a other class as its attribute ? soo the Customer for me is that first class ,and i would like to assign a room to it . is that correct to do it like : public class Customer {
    
    String name;
    int PESEL;
    Room room;
    
    Customer(String name,int PESEL){
    this.name=name;
    this.PESEL=PESEL;
    this.room=new Room(0);
    }

Comment: @rafalbballer yes that would be the way to create a customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I learned that you want a constructor for `Customer`. Here is one:

```
public class Customer {
    String name;
    int PESEL;
    Room room;

    // constructor for Customer with a room argument
    Customer(String name,int PESEL, Room room) {
        this.name=name;
        this.PESEL=PESEL;
        this.room = room;
        }
    }

    // constructor for Customer with a default room, though impractical :)
    Customer(String name,int PESEL) {
        this.name=name;
        this.PESEL=PESEL;
        this.room = new Room(0);
    }
}
```

Depending on the arguments passed to the `Customer`, the right constructor is invoked. For example, to create a `Customer` object with a `Room` assigned to it, you can do:

```
Room room = new Room(139);
Customer c = new Customer("Customer1", 10, room);
```

And to create a Customer with default room of 0, you can do this:

```
Customer c = new Customer("Customer1", 10);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem very Java-like to me. Instead, create two constructor. One with two arguments, one with three.

Comment: You should not use a default Room, there is no such thing in a hotel. If don't have a room for the customer, then you do not accommodate him. Introducing default rooms can lead to strange situations where you will have customer not actually in a room, or in a room with number 0, which does not exists, therefore the code becomes buggy.

Comment: @iullianr I know. It is what OP asked for.

Comment: @BramVanroy very true! I regret that! Will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to add a constructor to class Customer, which will receive three parameters:

```
Customer( String name, int PESEL, Room room) {... }
```

This because when you define a new Customer, you allocate to a room which you already have in the hotel (not occupied) so you should assign him an unoccupied room from the list of rooms you have.

To make the code more robust you can introduce a check in the constructor to see if the room object received as parameter is unoccupied, before assign it to the Customer. if it is occupied just raise an exception because the customer cannot be put in an occupied room.

If the Room parameter is null, that can mean you just register a Customer who wants to make a reservation, and you might not have a room number. However, having this king of logic depending on the null value is not very good. Is better just to have a different class which will model the reservation while the Customer class will only refer to the customers who actually got a room.